# How do I build a data frame of dates using seq.Date multiple times

Tags: r

```
endDt<-as.Date("2012-10-1")
dts<-as.Date(c("2010-1-1", "2010-3-1", "2012-10-1"))
```

How do I do something like the following:

```
endDts<-c() #an empty date vector

for each dt in dts
    append seq.Date(dt,endDt,by="3 months") to endDts
next dt
```

I ran into issues trying to loop through my vector of dates, `dts`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the data.frame to look like, but here's an idea: `Vectorize(seq.Date)(dts, endDt, by="3 months")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the excellent comment solution you can use `mapply`:

```
mapply(seq.Date,dts, endDt,by="3 months")

[[1]]
 [1] "2010-01-01" "2010-04-01" "2010-07-01" "2010-10-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-04-01" "2011-07-01"
 [8] "2011-10-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-04-01" "2012-07-01" "2012-10-01"

[[2]]
 [1] "2010-03-01" "2010-06-01" "2010-09-01" "2010-12-01" "2011-03-01" "2011-06-01" "2011-09-01"
 [8] "2011-12-01" "2012-03-01" "2012-06-01" "2012-09-01"

[[3]]
[1] "2012-10-01"
```